# Easiest way to set spark's connection timeout

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What's the easiest way to set a timeout for spark's connection methods, like read and write?

So far I tried to add "spark.network.timeout" with something really low, like "2s", but then I got an exception requesting for "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval" to be lower than the timeout, so I set the heartbeatInterval to "1s".

Setting the timeout:

```
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").config("spark.network.timeout","2s").config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "1s").getOrCreate();
```

Reading data:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset =  sparkSession.read().jdbc(url, fromStatement, properties);
```

Writing data:

```
dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(destinyUrl, tableName, accessProperties);
```

The read method took 11 seconds to load the dataset, and the write method took 13 seconds to save the dataset into the database, but no actions got stopped after the 2 seconds.

Comment: It works when write 'spark.network.timeout 2s' in conf/spark-default.conf file. Setting in SparkSession like a parameter has no effect.

Answer (score -4):

When there is no n/w issues you cant expect to get it stopped. `'spark.network.timeout'` is default for all network interactions. 
This config will be used in place if below properties are not configured.

```
  spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout,
  spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs,
  spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout
  spark.rpc.askTimeout or spark.rpc.lookupTimeout
```

where as `spark.executor.heartbeatInterval` is Interval between each executor's heartbeats to the driver. Heartbeats let the driver know that the executor is still alive and update it with metrics for in-progress tasks. spark.executor.heartbeatInterval should be significantly less than spark.network.timeout (default = 10s)

source : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!